# Trackback DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, debugging, dom

I'm stuck on a trackback for a DOM manipulation done by the core code of RainLoop.

There is an ajax request/response hook, which I have found, but after that there must be some other code (probably JavaScript or KnockoutJS) which manipulates data from a response before displaying them on the screen and I'm not able to find it in the RainLoop spaghetti code.

Is there any way to trackback part of that code via inspect element/DOM or some kind of debugging tool like Xdebug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many options I have ended up with Event Listener Breakpoints from Chrome. Not a perfect solution but is working in a minimal level required to find out what is effected DOM.